# SSO with ADFS on Mobile

Tags: javascript, node.js, ionic-framework, saml-2.0, adfs3.0

We have an existing app built on Ionic 3 which communicates with a sails.js API.
Today we are required to add an authentication system for a client based on their ADFS. 
Apparently this client already have Single Sign-On set up with multiple web apps, where they use SAML protocol.

I am very confused about how to implement such a thing and here are my questions:

- Is SAML the way to go (even for mobile) to build an authentication system ?
- I've seen ADFS implements Oauth2 endpoints, wouldn't that be an easier way ?
- What would the flow of information look like for a clean and secure implementation ?

Am I missing something ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: https://github.com/bergie/passport-saml#usage-with-active-directory-federation-services

Comment: I have tried using passport-saml, the thing is I don't know how to test it because I would need the client to authorize the test app (can't be local?). Any suggestions?

Comment: Also what URL should I provide passport config? As it is mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAML is not a good way to go for mobile. You need a SAML client side stack and there aren't many for mobile.

OpenID Connect / OAuth is a better way to go but ADFS 3.0 has very limited support for this.

Essentially it only supports [web API](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/25/securing-a-web-api-with-adfs-on-ws2012-r2-got-even-easier/).

The link above points to projects on Azure AD not ADFS.

Comment: That's what I figured. Thanks for confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Most SAML profiles make use of the browser. Profiles like Web Browser SSO (WBSSO) with HTTP_POST binding. The flow in that case is:

- User navigates to your app
- Your app redirects their browser to the client's SAML endpoint
- The SAML endpoint decides whether the user already has a session or needs to login.
- The client's SAML endpoint redirects the user's browser via a POST to your app with a body containing the attributes
- Your app unpacks the SAMLResponse parameter to get the SAML attributes and makes an authorisation decision based on those attributes. Perhaps they contain email address, name etc. It's up to your app how long a session to create based on that event.

In the above, your app acts as a SAML SP while the client's SAML endpoint acts the IdP.

For AD OAuth, you usually have to register your app as a tenant app to allow the other end to trust you. So you'd have to give them your URL where the attributes are sent via the browser. There is a great set of projects provided by Microsoft for implementing AD SSO at [gdal](https://github.com/AzureAD).